# how do I add code for a button on a viewcontroller?

Tags: xcode

How do I add code for a button on a ViewController?  For example, in VisualStudio, I can simply double-click on a button and it will take me to an auto-genned clicked handler for the button in the codebehind.  How do I go about doing something similar to this in xcode?

Comment: Ok I'm one step closer.  I need to 

1. select the storyboard viewcontroller view in the left Navigator
2. click on the Assistant Editor button for the IDE to display related code in the pane to the right
3. control + left mouse click the ui control in the storyboard to open the connections inspector
4. to handle button click, select the "touch up inside" connection and drag it to the code

However, I'm having problems identifying the proper code file that I can drag this connector to.  Can you provide some insight around the rules that I'm missing on this last step?

Comment: Post the snap of your code which you get after this process

Comment: The process I described doesn't generate any code.  From what I understand, I'm supposed to drag the connector reference to a code file and Xcode will auto-gen some code based on this reference.  I've tried this with 2 different code files in my project but no association is created.  The problem is that I'm trying to connect to the wrong file or in the wrong part of the file.  That's the grey area that I'm trying to get help with here.  In other words, which file and which part of the file should I drag to in order to make the association?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to generate button code.
1. Create button using drag and drop from the list of components.
[image: button created.]
Now click on this button(shown in second image )
[image: button]
It will automatically directs you in your code file.
But if some problems occurs to direct you jn your code file.
Follow this steps.
1. Click on your viewController where you added button. (In viewcontroller scene)
[image: view controller]
2. Click on the identity inspector check the class name. 
[image: class name]
3.Check same class name is there in the second part.
[image: class name is second part]
 If its same than now you can simple using control + three finger and drag it to your .swift file it will open it like this.
[image: button]
Now select action in connection to get button click action. And remains outlet to get the button property.

But if you are not getting the same file select here and find your file name in this hierarchy. After getting file do same process again.

[image: button]

Comment: You can use Command + Shift + 4 to screenshot a selected area.  It gives cleaner images than photographs of a screen.

Comment: Thanks Dhruv.  Here’s a screenshot of my Xcode IDE: 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q5uvdbcmq3vpqyf/viewcontroller%20-%20no%20class%20association.png?dl=0

I selected the parent ViewController for the button.  I clicked on the identify inspector but the class name displayed is just the default native UIViewController in light grey font.  I can’t and shouldn’t edit the native UIViewController class.  I would have assumed that Xcode would have auto-genned a new ViewController class to support my ViewController implementation.  Am I missing a step?

Comment: Just write viewController which is your swift file name and press enter it will allocate your viewController to viewController.swift file.

Answer (score 1):

Just do what I say it's simple.

1.Open File Navigator and Select your View's viewController.h file.

2.Now left click on your button and click+control drag  to viewController.h (make sure you drag between @interface ----   @end).

3.Give name to your method and make sure You select Action in Connection option.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqIEP.png)

4.Click connect and you will have your method declaration on viewcontroller.h .

5.Now switch to viewController.m and there you'll find your method at the end and there you will write all the defination of your method.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqIEP.png)

Comment: Thanks Kuldeep.  Assistant Editor > Automatic opens UIViewController.h. This appears to be a native/framework file that I shouldn't modify.  Should I expect Xcode to auto-gen some type of custom implementation-level view controller for me?  Or is this something that I need to do manually?